# asyncio.ensure_future on ElasticBeanstalk (Python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to use elastic beanstalk to run an asyncio python application.
elastic beanstalk seems to be running python 3.6.5 .

I'm getting errors when trying to using ensure_future from asyncio:

```
module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'ensure_future'
```

I also tried "from asyncio import ensure_future" and got the import error.

I've tried using .ebextensions to force upgrade of asyncio.
Also tried using requirements.txt to force asyncio to a version which I know works with my app (asyncio==3.4.3) but both to no avail.

Also tried

```
try:
  from asyncio import ensure_future
except ImportError:
  from asyncio import async as ensure_future
```

And then I just got an error when calling ensure_future:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File 
"main_async_tasks_crawler.py", line 96, in main
 asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(ensure_future(async_main()))
 File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncio/tasks.py", line 516, in async
raise TypeError('A Future or coroutine is required')
TypeError: A Future or coroutine is required
```

my argument (async_main()) is an async function..

I'm out of ideas at the moment

Comment: What does `ensure_future(async_main())` return? Is it an instance of [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete) or coroutine??

Comment: the exception is for the call ensure_future (actually async because for some reason elastic beanstalk's asyncio version seems to be outdated and doesn't want to update) - and async_main() returns an awaitable - as I said it's an async def.

Comment: What does `import sys; print(sys.path)` show? It is not usual to see `/python3.6/site-packages/asyncio`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncio` is a part of Python3.6 standard library, you must not install it via pip.

asyncio==3.4.3 is really old, at that time there was no such thing as "async function", so it doesn't know how to work with them.

Comment: Yes I was actually just on to this, so annoying I was on it for like 2 hours at least.  You beat me to it so you got the check-mark, thanks

Comment: This does not offer a solution